# Sci-fi short story collection: Scientist tries to find one final equation

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, anthology-book

I am looking for an anthology where one of the stories was about a scientist who leaves everything to find the one final equation or formula that will combine all equations.

The scientist was a man. He was tasked or obsessed with finding the one equation. The goal was to combine everything and thereby removing the existence of god. To find the final equation, he devoted all his time to research. He even lived alone for long time sacrificing all personal and social life. He nearly find it or close to finding it.

It was in an sci-fi anthology book, originally in Russian, but I read in English translated. Most probably one Russian author.

Comment: Hello Ameen, if you have any additional information, you can [edit] your question to add it. Also, you might want to take a look at [our guide to asking a good story ID](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/19561) to see if anything jogs your memory.

Comment: I suspect that you're refering to the "unified field theory".

Comment: Its true RDFozz. The scientist guy was so obsessed with finding the one equation that he shuns everything in life. He lives all alone in a house in the mountain or away from civilization. He feels he was just one step from finding it. But ultimately died of old age without finding it. 

Another story in that book was about a young couple who are in deep love but could not be together due to some kind of technology related censorship from government. I read it so long time ago, I wish i could remember it. The stories are like black mirror episodes. All are sci-fi with alternate world setting.